# What Cheese Culture is best to use in making Camembert cheese?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making

I'm planning to make camembert cheese but I'm confused on what cultures to add. Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  An excellent question, as it turns out.

Answer (score 4):

I can see why!  Let's do a round up:

- [Rikki Carroll](https://cheesemaking.com/products/camembert-recipe) recommends Flora Danica, Penicillium Candidum, and Geotrichum Candidum
- [Gavin Webber](https://www.littlegreencheese.com/2013/01/how-to-make-camembert.html) recommends Mesophilic direct set culture, plus Penicillium Candidum
- [Curd Nerd](https://curd-nerd.com/soft-cheese-recipes/camembert-2/) recommends Flora Danica and Penicillium Candidum
- [Country Brewer](https://www.countrybrewer.com.au/pages/how-to-make-camembert-cheese.html) recommends "camebert cheese culture" which doesn't help at all
- [Food52](https://food52.com/recipes/19281-camembert-cheese) recommends either Flora Danica or Mesophilic culture, and Penicillium

Given the above, I'd tend to go with Flora Danica and Penicillium Candidum, at least for a first try.  At least the amounts seem to be consistent: 1/4 and 1/8 teaspoon, respectively.  According to Carroll, the Geotrichum helps give the Camembert a thick, fuzzy white rind, so use it too if you can get it.

Caveat: I haven't made this cheese myself, and my friends who have aren't available for questions this weekend.

Comment: Nice collection! You could always invite your cheese maker friends to the site and have them share their wisdom in their own answers <hint, hint> ;-)

Comment: Lisa and David really don't care to.  I can bug them next week though.